# Remove CRLF from the middle of a file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, carriage-return, linefeed

I have been receiving a text file where each row should be 246 columns in length.  For some reason an errant CRLF is being inserted in the file after every 23,036 characters, causing all sorts of problems.

The file is in a windows format, all line endings are CRLF.

Is there some way to strip out these extra CR-LF characters from this file, without disturbing the CRLF that exists at the end of every other line?  Unix tools would be the preferred method here, if possible (awk, sed, etc).

Below is a sample of how the block of text looks like when there is an extra CRLF character added.  Please note, this file is 258 Meg in size, and that extra CRLF occurs along the line in different places further down the file.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a way of identifying these CRLFs?  Can you post a small example of what you're seeing?  It's most likely possible to remove these extras, but it's hard to come with a solution if we can't see the problem.

Comment: yeah let me try and work up a small sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your not sure what position, you can delete all line endings and add them at the right places:

```
(tr -d "\r\n" < my_inputfile | fold -w 245;echo) | sed 's/$/\r/'
```

The `echo` is needed, since `fold` will not add a newline for the last line.

Comment: Thanks.  When I am in the office next week, I will give this a try as well

Comment: This also works well.    I had to change the above to 246 characters per line, and direct STDOUT to another file, but otherwise nicely done

Comment: i am picking this answer only because it runs faster than the perl script.  Both work well however.  The awk command from the other suggestion is still messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple perl script that runs a loop, where in every iteration, it copies 23036 bytes to the output and then skips the CRLF that follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (1) {
    my $r=read STDIN,my $buf,23036;
    defined $r or die "error: $!";
    last if $r<23036;
    print $buf;
    my $c=read STDIN,my $crlf,2;
    defined $c or die "error: $!";
    $crlf eq "\r\n" or die "Not a CRLF";
}
```

You run it like this:

```
./myscript.pl < input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

Comment: I tried this and got: `Scalar found where operator expected at ./myscript.pl line 12, near "$crlf"  (Missing semicolon on previous line?)` and `syntax error at ./myscript.pl line 8, near "last "`  and `syntax error at ./myscript.pl line 12, near "$crlf "`

Comment: @z-vap Oops sorry, my bad. I had forgotten 2 semicolons.

Comment: it ended with `Not a CRLF at ./myscript.pl line 12.` which i assume was expected?  This certainly works.   It ran for about 2 minutes or so and made 11,332 total modifications.  I am currently validating the file is all there.

Comment: It probably complained about the last chunk, it was expecting it to be 23036 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

with awk

```
awk '
    length($0) != 247 {sub(/\r$/,""); printf "%s", $0; next} 
    {print}
' file
```

Note that "unix" text files have `\n` line endings, so `\r` is just a plain character. That's why I use 246+1 as the record length, and remove the CR from record fragments.

---

Update: yes, the above answer is incorrect: it will not properly append ONLY the next line, but the next TWO lines. Try this:

```
awk '
    length($0) != 247 {sub(/\r$/,""); printf "%s", $0; getline; print; next} 
    {print}
' file
```

When it detects a short line, remove the CR and print it with no newline. Then read the next line, which I assume is the rest of that record, and print it with the CR intact. Then move on to the next record.

Comment: Yes thanks.  When checking the file it does have Windows format line endings.  I will also try this out next week.

Comment: this did not work; it removed CRLF characters from the middle of the lines, but did not add the now missing CRLF  at the end.  Now lines 93 and 94 are mashed together in one long 492 character line.